# How to embed all fonts in PDF?

Tags: fonts, texlive, texstudio, windows, embedding

I am writing my thesis on `LaTeX` using `TeXstudio` and `Texlive` on PC with Windows 10.

I am using BT Charter, and for some reason I cannot get the font to embed to the .pdf file, and when I share the file with my supervisors for proofreading, he can't see some of the content because he doesn't have Charter font installed onto his PC.

I downloaded the Charter font from the internet and therefore it displays fine on my computer, but not my supervisor's computer.

I have added a MWE below. Figure1 is attached on filedropper link and was created in Origin software and uses Charter font. Could the problem be the figure because the font is not embeded to the figure itself?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=1.0,sups,lf]{XCharter} %Document body font
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figure1}
    \caption[Figure 1]{ caption}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[enter link description here](https://filedropper.com/d/s/X8ef0suaKXmcjFguba5ZlQ7HBT2plT)

[![Figure1 on filedropper. Figure1 is in pdf format][2]][2]

Comment: One workaround might be to use the XCharter font included with TeX live.

Comment: It would probably be useful to have a full but minimal example of how you're using BT Charter in your document.

Comment: We'd need to see an MWE to make sure. Normally the point of using a PDF is enable others to read the document without having to have the same fonts as you.

Comment: Could you please edit a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) into the question, so we can see what you’re doing?

Comment: I have added MWE now. Thanks.

Comment: Do realise that we don't have that image. Might be an idea to remove it.

Comment: Note that the example you provide does not use anywhere near the fonts you listed. And at least for my TL2022 embeds all fonts.

Comment: @Benzene Yes, the problem is the figure. All the fonts used by TeX are already embedded. So to fix the document, you have to fix the figure.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks. It looks like that is the problem. I will see if I can find a solution for embedding font to figures created in OriginPro. Cheers.